# Проверка float на NAN и INFINITY на си

Tags: c

Как правильно проверить float на NAN и INFINITY на си?
Сделал вот так:

```
   if(res == NAN || res == -NAN)
   {
   res = 0;
   }
   if(res == INFINITY)
   {
   res = FLT_MAX;
   }
   if(res == -INFINITY)
   {
   res = -FLT_MAX;
   }
```

где res --- float.

Comment: `NaN` не равен ни чему, даже самому себе, поэтому на него можно проверить либо так `res != res`, либо с помощью [`isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan). А с бесконечностью можно сравнивать простым сравнением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать специальные средства - [`isnan(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) и [`isinf(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isinf).